# How to add images below the sidebar in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css

I am building a website in http://calgarydefencelaw.com/. But the main problem i am facing is that the 3 images i have entered that is impaired driving not aligning well. I want to align all the three images below sidebar any suggestion
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `clear: both;` style to div with id `imageboxes`.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your requirement you need to display the 3 boxes below the sidebar.
Just put the html

```
<div id="imageboxes">
<div id="homebox1">
<div id="homebox2">
<div id="homebox3">
</div>
```

inside  instead of writing it outside and add #imageboxes div{padding-left: 5px;} instead of margin-left:15px;